# Not adding values to database

Tags: php, mysql

I just created ajax function which sends data to php and php to database. Inserting to dotp_task_log table, works fine. But further, when I need to add data to dotp_tasks after adding to dotp_task_log, it isn't adding, and I cant find why... I get the Gerror, Here is my php file which adds data to database.

```
<?php
$currentUser = isset($_POST['currentUser']) ? $_POST['currentUser'] : '';
$currentTasken = isset($_POST['currentTasken']) ? $_POST['currentTasken'] : '';
$currentPercent = isset($_POST['currentPercent']) ? $_POST['currentPercent'] : '';
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
    if(!$con)
        die('Could not connectzzz: ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("foxi" , $con) or die ("could not load the database" . mysql_error());

    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dotp_task_log");
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($check);
    if($numrows >= 1)
    {
        //$pass = md5($pass);

        $ins = mysql_query("INSERT INTO dotp_task_log (task_log_creator, task_log_Task) VALUES ('$currentUser' , '$currentTasken')" ) ;

        if($ins)
        {
                $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dotp_tasks");
                $numrows = mysql_num_rows($check);
                if($numrows > 1)
                {
                    //$pass = md5($pass);

                    $inss = mysql_query("INSERT INTO dotp_tasks (task_percent_complete) VALUES ('$currentPercent') WHERE task_id='$currentTasken'" ) ;

                    if($inss)
                    {
                        die("Succesfully added Percent!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        die("GERROR");
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    die("Log already exists!");
                }
        }
        else
        {
            die("ERROR");
        }

    }
    else
    {
        die("Log already exists!");
    }


?>
```

Comment: Error checking. [1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) - [2](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php)

Comment: reload my comment, they're hyperlinks

Comment: Have you tried printing out the full query to the screen? It might be obvious that a value is missing etc. Also try running the query manually in your mysql client and see what error it gives.

Comment: Oh, INSERT... doesn't have a `WHERE` clause. [Error checking](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) would have signaled the syntax error. INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY does. You may have wanted to use UPDATE instead. ;-) so there's the problem.

Comment: So write in answers how it should look like

Comment: I have posted one below. I was busy writing it up and gathering reference links.

Comment: Please read this link to learn about the right way to do mysql statements that don't leave your web app open to SQL injection attacks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Do you know why i get ReferenceError: Patikrinta is not defined jsfiddle.net/uaae0xcy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I stated in comments:

> *INSERT... doesn't have a `WHERE` clause. [Error checking](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) would have signaled the syntax error. [INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) does. You may have wanted to use UPDATE instead*

```
$inss = mysql_query("UPDATE dotp_tasks 
                     SET task_percent_complete = '$currentPercent' 
                     WHERE task_id='$currentTasken'" );
```

References:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Plus, do use error checking when testing:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

instead of echoing custom messages.

Add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

Footnotes:

- Make sure your HTML form does hold a POST method and that all inputs bear the name attributes and no typos. Using error reporting, will signal that.
- Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

Comment: Do you know why i get ReferenceError: Patikrinta is not defined jsfiddle.net/uaae0xcy

Comment: @TorresAlGrande reload my answer if you haven't seen the part about your HTML form/elements and error reporting. JS isn't my bag, sorry.

Comment: Cant find where you write about this https://jsfiddle.net/uaae0xcy/
**ReferenceError: Patikrinta is not defined**

Comment: @TorresAlGrande Again, the problem may lie in your HTML form. JS isn't what I'm good at.

Answer (score 2):

Fred -ii- nailed it in his comment - you're using improper syntax in that query.

It looks like you want an update query, for example:

```
update dotp_tasks 
set task_percent_complete = '$currentPercent' 
where task_id = '$currentTasken'
```

Additionally - it's always best to avoid creating queries by formatting strings manually - you'll want to look into [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to improve this code further.

Comment: Do you know why i get `ReferenceError: Patikrinta is not defined` https://jsfiddle.net/uaae0xcy/